# Changing to large letters in the header

Tags: header-footer

Good day!
I am creating a title "Translation dB, dBm"
Now I want to put this header in the header using "fancyhdr", but it prints all letters in all caps. This is good, and I like it, but dB becomes DB, and this is already a mistake.
The question is: is it possible to somehow indicate that dB does not become all capital letters (DB), and let the rest of the text remain in large letters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage 
\section{Translation dB, dBm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fancyhdr` package does provide a `\nouppercase` command that turns the capitalization it normally does off.

To get something like you want, here’s a bit of a hack.  Load `fontaxes`, which provide `\textsc` to select small caps and `\textulc` to turn small caps off.  Then load a font that contains a Cyrillic small caps face.¹

With the `fontaxes` package, you can select the *primary shape* (such as slanted) and the *secondary shape* (such as small caps) separately.  It gives you `\textsc` and `\textulc` commands to turn small caps on and off.  This lets you combine slanted text, like in the default `fancy` page style, with small caps text—and specify individual words that should not be in small caps with `\textulc{dB}`.

I also took a few other liberties, such as turning on the `[twopage]` option, turning on `microtype`, and loading Unicode fonts in engines that support them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english,russian,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
  \babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=Common, Language=Default, Scale=1.0]{Erewhon}
  \babelfont{sf}[Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}, Language=Default]{Libertinus Sans}
  \babelfont{tt}[Language=Default]{Libertinus Mono}
  \setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\else
  \usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{cmap}
  \usepackage{babel}
  % Loads a Type 1 font family that supports Cyrillic slanted small caps,
  % along with a matching math font, a sans-serif font and a typewriter font.
  \usepackage{libertinus-type1}
  \usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
  \usepackage{fontaxes} % For \textsc, \textulc, etc.
\fi
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\babeltags{english=english}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\arabic{section}.~\textsc{#1}}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{{\slshape\scshape\selectfont\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage
\begin{english}
\section{Translation \textulc{dB}, \textulc{dBm}}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image: Erewhon font sample]

¹ As of 2020, the following 8-bit font families define a `{scsl}` NFSS shape for the `{T2A}` ecoding: Libertinus, Erewhon, Garamond Libre, XCharter, Noto, and Old Standard.  Several of those do not actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks! It works! It seems to me that there is a lot of unnecessary here. Here is the minimum that continues to work. However, the word "content" is repeated on every page, although this is not necessary, and the inscriptions in the footer are located on the left and then on the right, that is, in a bookish manner. Fixing that would be great!

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english,russian,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
\fi
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\arabic{section}.~\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 
    \clearpage
        \section{Translation \textulc{dB}, \textulc{dBm}}
        \newpage
        \section{Translation \textulc{dBtrr}, \textulc{dBmerer}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Write in english, please.